# mysql syntax issue, error 1064 42000

Tags: mysql

I am receiving this error. I was wondering if I am missing something obvious:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage (
  ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  powerType VARCHAR(100),
  usageD' at line 1
```

This is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,


username VARCHAR(100),
  hashPass VARCHAR(100),
  firstName VARCHAR(100),
  lastName VARCHAR(100),
  address1 VARCHAR(100),
  address2 VARCHAR(100),
  city VARCHAR(100),
  state VARCHAR(100),
  zip INT(5),
  userRole VARCHAR(100),
  clientID INT(10),
  email VARCHAR(100),
  phone1 VARCHAR(100),
  phone2 VARCHAR(100),
   PRIMARY KEY(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY(clientID) REFERENCES Clients(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Clients (
  ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  companyName VARCHAR(100),
  address1 VARCHAR(100),
  address2 VARCHAR(100),
  city VARCHAR(100),
  state VARCHAR(100),
  zip INT(5),
  phone1 VARCHAR(100),
  phone2 VARCHAR(100),
  clientID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ServiceAccounts (
  ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  accountNumber VARCHAR(100),
  email VARCHAR(100),
  companyEmail VARCHAR(100),
  phone1 VARCHAR(100),
  phone2 VARCHAR(100),
  clientID INT(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (clientID) REFERENCES Clients(ID)

);

CREATE TABLE Usage (
  ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  powerType VARCHAR(100),
  usageDate DATE,
  startTime TIME,
  endTime TIME,
  usage DECIMAL(10,2),
  unitsType VARCHAR(100),
  cost DECIMAL(10, 2),
  accountNumber VARCHAR(100),
  serviceAccountID INT(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (serviceAccountID) REFERENCES ServiceAccounts(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Meters (
  ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  meterID VARCHAR(100),
  serviceAccountID INT(10),
  address1 VARCHAR(100),
  address2 VARCHAR(100),
  city VARCHAR(100),
  state VARCHAR(100),
  zip INT(5),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (serviceAccountID) REFERENCES ServiceAccounts(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE RateTiers (
  ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TierID VARCHAR(100),
  rateTierID INT,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
);
```

Also, I don't know if this is related... but Sublime2 highlights `VARCHAR` and `INT`, but it doesn't highlight `TIME` or `DECIMAL`. Why doesn't it recognize these as types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Usage` is a reserved word: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

You'll have to escape it with backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE `Usage` ...
             ^-----^---
```